# Is this boxplot notch correct?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Need an explanation for this weird looking boxplot notch.
I've provided the data and the code before plotting (using `ggplot2`)

The notch looks inverted on top. How can this be explained?
I've never encountered a notch like this.

[image: weirdnotch]

```
df<-read.table(text =   '   SU AGC.low    AGB
1   1   22.12  48.09
2   2   10.14  22.04
3   3   18.23  39.63
4   4   36.14  78.57
5   5   47.56 103.39
6   6   38.98  84.74
7   7   47.74 103.78
8   8   15.17  32.98
9  10   30.24  65.74
10 11   33.28  72.35
11 15   40.27  87.54', header=TRUE, sep="")

df = subset(df, select = -c(AGC.low))

dfm <- melt(df[,c('SU','AGB')],id.vars = 1)
str(dfm)
dfm$SU<-as.factor(dfm$SU) #dit is ook nodig voor collaps x - as 

view(dat)
view(dfm)

# Make a boxplot for AGB
# Trim data frame 
# Remove SU column 
box_dfm = subset(dfm, select = -c(SU))
names(box_dfm)
names(box_dfm)[2] <- "AGB" 
#names(box_dfm)[1] <- "AGB" 

library(ggplot2)
# Change outlier, color, shape and size
p<-ggplot(box_dfm, aes(x=variable, y=AGB, color=variable)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="black", outlier.shape=20,outlier.size=2,notch=TRUE)+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,160,20))+
  ggtitle("Plot scale Biomass") +
  xlab("Variable") + ylab("Biomass Mg B/ ha")+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

Comment: See `?boxplot.stats`. The "notches (if requested) extend to +/-1.58 IQR/sqrt(n)". Since they are symmetrical around the median, they can re-curve when the data are asymmetrical. They provide a simple approximation of the confidence limits, but that is all.

Answer (score 3):

This boxplot is just a summary of the data. Reading the documentation for `geom_boxplot`:

> The lower and upper hinges correspond to the first and third quartiles (the 25th and 75th percentiles).

Computing the upper hinge this gives

```r
quantile(box_dfm$AGB, .75)
#>   75% 
#> 86.14
```

The notched box is defined as:

> In a notched box plot, the notches extend 1.58 * IQR / sqrt(n).

```r
n <- nrow(box_dfm)
median(box_dfm$AGB) + (IQR(box_dfm$AGB) * 1.58 / sqrt(n))
#> 92.49168
```

If you had more data the width of the notch would be narrower. For this asymmetric case it ends up as an inverted notch.